# Cant tell why is there any problen with "std::min" function CPP

Tags: c++

Here is the code sample:

```
std::min(1, 2, [](int x, int y)
    {std::cout << x  << ' ' << y << std::endl; return true;});
```

I get the next code ERROR:

> Expression: invaild operator <

Someone have an idia why this kind of ERROR may happend??

Comment: Checking my Mystery Black Box for answers ... Nope,... Nothing.... Trying Voodoo magic... Nope. Please post a [Complete, Minimal and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @WhiZTiM Not funny.. this is really everything and thats why I dont know What to do with that.. so lets stop with being funny people and become good to each other...

Comment: I can't duplicate your error.

Comment: @fgefgefgv WhiZTiM is right though, [I cannot repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/393a9505887e0d6b) this issue with the code you provided.

Comment: I suggest posting a full tiny c++ program we can copy paste, and gives you the error. I can't reproduce either. Also mention the compiler.

Comment: Maybe your failing code got a space inside what you meant to be a stream insertion operator?

Comment: I got a similar error for this: `std::min(1, 2,  [](int x, int y){ std::cout << x << ' ' << y < std::endl; return true; });` (note the `<` instead of `<<` before the `std::endl`) I also got a lot of template vomit.

Comment: Is the error a compile time or runtime error?

Comment: Might be handy if people said what compiler(s) they are using. This is not reproducible for me with GCC 5.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the algorithm requires that the comparison function would satisfy the requirement of the *strict weak ordering*. It means that for example if `comp( a, b )` is true then `comp( b, a )` is not true.  However in your call of the algorithm comp( x, y ) where comp is the lambda expression is true and comp( y, x ) is also true. It seems that in the debug mode the compiler switches on such a check of the comparison function.

Comment: @FredLarson: Why do you doubt it?

Comment: @FredLarson: You are assuming it is a compile error, instead of a runtime error. Some standard library implementations do in fact do these kind of checks in debug mode. The main problem here is of course that the OP failed to specify.

Comment: @FredLarson It can be  a run-time check.

Comment: After some looking, it appears it is a Windows runtime error message. I stand corrected. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5786296/10077

Comment: @FredLarson It is an error message generated by the library in the debug mode when the strict weak ordering is checked.

Comment: @FredLarson Here is the nessage    ? (_DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid comparator", _File, _Line), true)